# Why does catch not properly invoke handler when using Maybe?

Tags: haskell, exception, lazy-evaluation, catch-block

Consider the following Haskell code

```
try_lex_rgx :: String -> IO (Maybe [RgxToken])

try_lex_rgx rgx_str =
  catch
    (do
        rgx_toks <- evaluate $ lex_rgx rgx_str
        return $ Just rgx_toks)
    (\(LexerErr err_msg remainder) -> disp_lex_error rgx_str (LexerErr err_msg remainder))
```

The way I intend for this code to work is to evaluate the expression `lex_rgx rgx_str`, catching any exceptions when they occur, and then invoking `disp_lex_error` to pretty-print the error.

(By the way, the code for disp_lex_error is the following

```
disp_lex_error :: String -> RgxLexerException -> IO (Maybe [RgxToken])

disp_lex_error rgx_str (LexerErr err_msg remainder) = let loc_str_frag = "In regex " ++ rgx_str ++ " at ..." in
                                                        do 
                                                            hPutStrLn stderr ("Lexer error: " ++ err_msg ++ "\n" ++ 
                                                                              loc_str_frag ++ remainder ++ "\n" ++
                                                                              (replicate (length loc_str_frag - 1) ' ') ++ "^^")
                                                            evaluate Nothing
```

)

However, I think lazy evaluation is stopping this from happening. When I run the code in ghci with an input that invokes an error, I get the following message

```
*Rgx.RgxLexer> :l Rgx.RgxLexer
[1 of 2] Compiling Rgx.RgxTok       ( Rgx/RgxTok.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Rgx.RgxLexer     ( Rgx/RgxLexer.hs, interpreted )
Ok, two modules loaded.
*Rgx.RgxLexer> try_lex_rgx "\\"
Just [*** Exception: LexerErr "Dangling \"\\\" is not allowed" ""
```

instead of a pretty printed error.

To me, it seems as though the code is not working as I intend it to because due to lazy evaluation, the system only actually calculates the expression `evaluate $ lex_rgx rgx_str`
once it has already started forming the parent expression `Just x`.

Am I correct, and if so, is there any elegant way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: In haskell IO is strict, so `evaluate`'s effects are evaluated strictly. However, it's return value might still be lazy. This is not a problem if you throw your parse errors with `throwIO` or `throwM`, but it is a problem if you use just `throw`. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 4):

`evaluate` only evaluates a value to WHNF (i.e., to match `(:)` or `[]`, but not further), but your error is hidden inside an element of the list. The following function forces all elements of a list (or use the deepseq library for a more general interface).

```hs
-- Evaluates each element to WHNF (which might not be enough for all use cases)
evaluateList :: [a] -> IO [a]
evaluateList xs = evaluate (foldr seq () xs) >> pure xs
```

However hiding exceptions in elements is a questionable methodology to begin with, consider refactoring the lexer to not use exceptions, producing an informative `Either` that relays all possible errors, instead of using `Maybe` whose `Just` doesn't even guarantee a successful parse.

Comment: I did try using deepseq's force method but the issue persisted. In any case, I think I will refactor the code to not use exceptions. Thank you for the suggestion.